# Android and iOS Firebase database data merge

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Android app that uses Firebase database and planning to build an iOS counter part of it. Can I use the same Firebase database of my Android app? If not, is there a way to merge the datas in the Android Firebase database and iOS Firebase database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i use the same firebase database of my android app?

Yes you can. You need to go to your Firebase Console, select your project, add app and select iOS. Provide all the necessary details for the package name. Download the latest JSON file and add it to your project.

> if not is there a way to merge the datas in the android firebase database and iOS firebase database?

There aren't two databases, an Android database and an iOS database. There is a single database that can be accessed by Android and iOS apps.